# WinRT XAML: Application share not working properly

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

```
    private void OnDataRequested(DataTransferManager sender, DataRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Title = obj.Title + " - ";
        string html = "";
        textContent.SelectAll();
        html = textContent.SelectedText;
        textContent.Select(textContent.SelectionStart, textContent.SelectionStart);
        e.Request.Data.Properties.Description = html;
        e.Request.Data.SetText(html);
    }
```

Above is my code which I am using to share text in my Winrt Tablet application.

it works fine on emulator but in surface devices when I share my text it remove spaces between the paragraph.

on this line

```
e.Request.Data.SetText(html);
```

html contains this string

"\r\nAs an added service,\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nIt is therefore extremely important \r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\nPlease note that SMS service is an added service only\r\n\r\n\r\n"

But when I share it using mail app shows me this string.

As an added service,It is therefore extremely important Please note that SMS service is an added service only

While it should be like this:

As an added service,

It is therefore extremely important

Please note that SMS service is an added service only

**Correction :**

It is not working on emulator also, actually it is behaving like this when shared with outlook store app.

while sharing with one note is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `SetHtmlFormat` ?

Ref : http://www.4sln.com/Articles/windows-phone-8-1-share-contract-share-source

Comment: actually only variable name is html but it has simple string not html. and it is not working while sharing with outlook store app

Comment: I mean :  e.Request.Data.SetHtmlFormat(your text with spaces)

Comment: will try it tommorrow

Comment: If this answer is working for you, please accept it as answer to help others get it quickly :)

Comment: We can't share this because there is a problem with the content.  This error is coming which is quite obvious as i am setting simple text as htmlformat

Comment: OK, try to set the content as HTML with some spaces & lines